# Node.js Is this a great way to show pages in a minimal way as possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a Node.js server as minimal as possible to show a landing page, but i'm not sure this is the greatest and fastest way to do it.

I'm using dirty to store my html data.

**My app.js file**

```
var http = require('http')
, db = require('dirty')('pages.db')
, url = require('url')
, fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var html = db.get(pathname);

    //Check if the requsted file is CSS or JS
    if (/\.(css)$/.test(pathname) || /\.(js)$/.test(pathname)){

        fs.createReadStream(__dirname + pathname, {
            'bufferSize': 4 * 1024
        }).pipe(response)

    } else if (!!html && pathname !== '/admin' ) {
        //Pages from our Dirty DB
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(html);
    } else if (pathname === '/admin') {
        //Display Admin page
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('Admin!');
    } else {
        //Show 404 Page
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(db.get('404'));
    }
 }).listen(80);

console.log('Server running at http://192.168.56.101:80/');
```

Comment: You question is a little vague. You code looks acceptable... you may want to add a response.end() after .pipe(response), I'm not sure if it's really necessary though. Also it seems like your assuming paths will always be in lower case, is it alright to assume  that url.parse(request.url) will produce lowercase paths?

Comment: Adding response.end() seems to break the code. And with the lowercase paths, yes I do assume they will be all lowercase.

Comment: According to the documentation for `stream`, `pipe()` will call the destination's `end()` method when the source stream emits an `end` event, unless you use `{ end: false }` as its second argument. Calling `end()` more than once on a stream is an error.

Answer (score 2):

Good question,
made me learn some more about `dirty`.

Some observations:

- 1 `var` block is good, having the commas not at the end of each line looks odd
- I wonder if it is faster to get the extension of the requested resource and compare to `js` and `css` instead of executing 2 regexes
- Your 3 `if` blocks contain the same statement: `response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});` you should extract that statement into 1 place.
- '80' should be in a `var` which you then use for your last `console.log` statement
- Similarly, hard coding the ip address in your `log` statement does not make sense, you should get that info from node.
- Always calculating 4*1024 and creating an options object seems like a lot work, that ought to get done only once
  *

I would counter propose something like this:

```
var http = require('http'),
    db = require('dirty')('pages.db'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    port = 80,
    streamOptions = { 'bufferSize': 4 * 1024 },
    htmlHeader = {'Content-Type': 'text/html'};

http.createServer(function (request, response)
{
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  var html = db.get(pathname);

  //First check if the requsted file is css or js
  if (/\.(css)$/.test(pathname) || /\.(js)$/.test(pathname))
  {
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + pathname,streamOptions).pipe(response);
  } 
  else 
  {
    response.writeHead(200, htmlHeader );
    if (!!html && pathname !== '/admin' ) 
    { //Pages from our Dirty DB 
      response.end(html); 
    } 
    else if (pathname === '/admin') 
    { //Display Admin page
      response.end('Admin!'); 
    } 
    else 
    { //Not found..
      response.end(db.get('404'));
    }
  }
 }).listen(port);

console.log('Server running on port' , port );
```

If you absolutely want to show the IP address, then you should check out this excellent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653065/7602).

Finally, any hacker can access your admin pages with `/./admin` tricks unless either `dirty` or `url` is smarter than I give it credit for.